# Hide columns on button click in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-angular

I need hide VAD group columns on button click. Please help me. [image]

Comment: May I know if you are using Ag-grid on vanilla JS? Or Angular?

Comment: I'm using ReactJS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Column API`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/#column-keys) methods:

> **`setColumnVisible(colKey, visible)`** Sets the visibility of a column. Key can be the column id or Column object.

or

> **`setColumnsVisible(colKeys, visible)`** Same as setColumnVisible, but provide a list of column keys.

```
hide(){
    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnsVisible(['columnNameOne', 'columnNameTwo'], false);
}

show(){
    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnsVisible(['columnNameOne', 'columnNameTwo'], true);
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fbmqWDCPkKuXeEqFW54p?p=preview)</kbd>